# Cannot pass value from main.js to index.html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the vue object I create in main.js with a value : myName

```
import Vue from "vue";

const vm = Vue.createApp({
    data () {
        return {
            myName: 'su'
        }
    }
});

vm.mount('#app');
```

and I'd like to show 'su' in index.html

here is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    123
    <div id="app">
      name : {{ myName }}
    </div>
    
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and it does't work and show

name : {{ myName }}

Can anyone help pls thanks!

Comment: Next time, please at least consult your browser's developer tools console for errors before asking on StackOverflow. The console would have clearly showed you `Vue is undefined`.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the answer correct. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're never actually importing `Vue`. Checking your browser console would have shown you that `Vue is undefined`.

```
import Vue from "vue";
```

needs a build tool like webpack and will resolve the import against your  `node_modules` folder.

Since you are directly importing Vue in a module right in your page, you need to import from a path available to the browser:

```html
123
<div id="app">
  name : {{ myName }}
</div>

<script type="module">
  import * as Vue from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'; 
  const vm = Vue.createApp({ 
    data () { 
      return { 
        myName: 'su' 
      } 
    } 
  }); 
  vm.mount('#app');
</script>
```

Comment: my question is how to pass the value from main.js, the first code is my main.js  and my browser  didn't show any error

Comment: I already tried your way and it works but that is not what I am trying to fix

Comment: That is the only reason Vue is not processing your `{{ myName }}`. Vue is not active at all.

Comment: so is it possible that i create vm in my main.js and pass the value to index.html?

Comment: Sure, that is the most basic stuff in Vue. It's just Vue doesn't work if Vue is never loaded :)

Comment: so it i fix  ```import Vue from "vue";```  in my main.js it may work?

Comment: *and my browser didn't show any error* Did you check the browser's **console**? Your browser must show you `Vue is undefined` there.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createApp' of undefined

Comment: Every browser's error messages differ in what they read. When `Vue` is `undefined`, trying to access `creatApp` of `Vue` results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createApp' of undefined`. If these total basics are unknown to you, it is a really bad idea to try and learn a framework like Vue.js. You will run into many problems, none of which you will ever be able to understand, debug, let alone fix. Learn Javascript before trying to build anything with a 3rd party library or framework.

Comment: thx a lot, I know where the problem is now